# What would be a value of $X$ under an automorphism of $F(X)$ over $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\sigma:F(X)\rightarrow F(X)$ be a field automorphism fixing $F$.

What would be an value of $\sigma(X)$?

Since $X$ is transcendental over $F$, $\sigma(X)$ is a transcendental over $F$ and $F(X)=F(\sigma(X))$. Let's define $\beta=\sigma(X)$.

Then, $X=f(\beta)/g(\beta)$ and $\beta=p(X)/q(X)$ for some polynomials $f,g,p,q$.

Why do $p,q$ have the degree $1$?

Edit :

Here's the solution:

[image]

It says $p,q$ must be of degree $1$, but I have no idea why. It's an exercise 38 in chapter 48, Fraleigh-Algebra.

Comment: Why do you believe that $p,q$ have degree $1$ ?

Comment: @Belgi I don't believe it, but t's written in a solution for this exercise that $p,q$ must have the degree $1$.(Removing common divisors) and I have no idea why..

Comment: Where is it written? What's the context?

Comment: @Timbuc I added it

Comment: Hmmm...Could it be you're in the surroundings of Lüroth's Theorem? Anyway, and using your notation: if $\;t:=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\;,\;\;(P,Q)=1\;,\;\;Q\neq 0\;$ , then try to prove that $$[F(x):F(t)]=\max\{\deg P\,,\,\deg Q\}$$ This part is fairly easy and short, but the continuation is rather lengthy and more involved.

Comment: @Timbuc Would you give me some hints? That seems not really easy to prove..

Comment: @Timbuc I don't even get why $F(X)/F(t)$ is algebraic. Why would be an $f\in F(t)[Y]$ such that $f(X)=0$..?

Comment: @Rubertos Using the above notation, what do you think about $$P(x)-tQ(x)\in F(t)[x]\;?$$ After this, what about $\;F[t][x]=F[x][t]\;?\; $ We could use this last to apply Gauss's lemma and prove the above poylonomial is irreducible in the field $\;F(t)\;$ ...